# Issue in creating json array with values from sqlite database

Tags: android, json

What i have done so far is: I have created a json object of this format :

`{
    "checklist": 
    {

                "id": "1",
        "name": "shoppping",
        "desc":"description",
        "is_editable":"false",
          "item": [
                {"id":"3","value": "dfdf", "desc": "wwe"},
                {"id":"3","value": "dfdf", "desc": "wwe"},
                {"id":"3","value": "dfdf", "desc": "wwe"}
                    ]
    }
}`

using the following code :

```
public static void sendjsontourl(String id) throws JSONException, IllegalStateException, IOException
{
 String title;
 String desc;
 String creator;
 Boolean is_editable;

 String[] itid;
 String[] itname;
 String[] itdesc;
 Boolean[] itchk;
 Integer count;

 title=DBInterface.getlistname(id);
 desc=DBInterface.getlistdesc(id);
 creator=DBInterface.getlistcreartor(id);
 is_editable=DBInterface.geteditablemode(id);     
 itid=DBInterface.getitemid(id);
 itname=DBInterface.getitemname(id);
 itdesc=DBInterface.getitemdesc(id);
 itchk=DBInterface.readdataitem(id);
 count=DBInterface.getitemcount(id);     

 JSONObject checklist = new JSONObject();
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
 JSONArray item = new JSONArray();
 JSONObject reqObj = new JSONObject();   
 for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
 {

    reqObj.put( "id",""+itid[i]);
    reqObj.put( "value",""+ itname[i]);
    reqObj.put( "desc", ""+itdesc[i] );
    item.put( reqObj );
 }        
    obj.put( "item", item );
    obj.put("id",""+id);
    obj.put("name",""+title);
    obj.put("description",""+desc);
    obj.put("creator",""+creator);
    obj.put("is_editable",""+is_editable);      
    checklist.put("checklist",obj);
    Log.d("log_tag",String.valueOf(checklist));
}
```

My issue: As u can see the json object which contains a json array-item ..the item's values are same for each and every item...The data fetching part from sqlite database is correct..I cannot fig out whats the problem and why the last indexed value only is stored in the json array!

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same instance of JSONObject for reqObj so you over write your data edit:

```
for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
 {
    JSONObject reqObj = new JSONObject();
    reqObj.put( "id",""+itid[i]);
    reqObj.put( "value",""+ itname[i]);
    reqObj.put( "desc", ""+itdesc[i] );
    item.put( reqObj );
 }
```